# Clone disappears, and the original remains, as do the opposite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such structure:

```
<div class="anotherDiv"></div>
<div class="group">
        <div class="clusters-group-container popup-panel-bg">
          <div class="group-container">BLOCK</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this Javascript code Javascript + Javascript UI:

```
$(".group").draggable({
            containment: 'document',
            zIndex: 9999,
            helper: 'clone',
            appendTo: '.anotherDiv'
});
```

**I need to:**

1) Block should move

2) When you click on the Block creates a clone. This is a must, otherwise the block will go to other div's.

3) moved to just clone and the original div should disappear, ie clicked the mouse clone move, but the original disappeared.

4) Once moved clone, it should not disappear!
Ie actually be just as if it were:

```
$(".group").draggable();
```

But only with the clone (mine another DIV)

http://jsfiddle.net/33u3xysa/

Comment: Okay? So what's your question? If (2) is a must, show us the code you tried to make that work. You just have a "draggable" div at the moment, you don't have any code to show for your attempt to do what you say you need to do yet.

Comment: Honestly, I have shown that I have at the moment. If you show more, then I would not have created this "issue".

Comment: I know this is what you have, but as a question on Stackoverflow, it's not enough - if you say you need to clone, then finding out how to clone a node in JavaScript is a simple web search away: there are tons of websites that tell you how to do that. Try to make it work. If you can't, *then* you have a good question to ask (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Right now, you have code that works, does what it should do, and just isn't what you need. So first try to make it do what you want, and then if you have code that you think should work but doesn't, *that's* a SO question.